# shared SQL Database instance in DEV environment

Tags: sql-server, licensing

I am in the process of consolidating sql 2000 and SQL 2005 databases and for the DEV environment the SQL Server instances are shared i.e. diff app databases share the same instance. What reasons/justification can I give for the app team as per the management they would want to save on licensing costs.

Please advise.

Thanks
hash

Comment: Are you asking what you should tell the app team as far as why it's the right thing to do, or what you should say to the management team to convince them it's the wrong thing to do? I am unclear based on your wording what you are asking.

Comment: Are you trying to save on windows licences, hardware costs? SQL Dev edition is essentially free

Answer (score 1):

Developer edition licenses are basically free.  What license costs are you trying to save?